# Solr search index on different tokens of a sentence

Tags: solr

Folks,

We wanted to make a search on solr such that it will give a priority to partial match in the sentences.

Lets say for example :

Sentence is like "Have wonderful evening today here"

- If user is supplying "today here" then it should match.
- If user is supplying "wonderful evening" then it should match.
- If user is supplying "Have wonderful" then it should match.

We want to give low priority to key word search compared to above.

keyword match could be : "today" "wonderful" "evening" etc.

Is there any way this can be achieve is solr since solr works on inverted index of words on a given sentence.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a separate field with a [SingleFilter](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Filter+Descriptions#FilterDescriptions-ShingleFilter) defined - this will combine runs of tokens into separate tokens, so that "Have wonderful evening today here" can be indexed as "have wonderful", "wonderful evening", "evening today" and "today here".

Make hits in this field a higher priority than hits in your regular search field by using `qf=shinglefield^<boostvalue>` - what the exact boost value needs to be depends on the scoring profile of your index and if you're doing other boosts.

```
<analyzer>
  <tokenizer class="solr.WhitespaceTokenizerFactory"/>
  <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
  <filter class="solr.ShingleFilterFactory" maxShingleSize="2" outputUnigrams="false"/>
</analyzer>
```